# Getting blank values from xml

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'am parsing a xml file in order to get some values,everything seems fine exept when i displayed the values that i get them from xml,they'are blank

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable  {
    SpringApplication.run(SwiftApplication.class, args);

    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();



      //On utilise notre fichier de test

      File file = new File("/home/dhafer/Downloads/Connector's Files/file.xml");



      //Nous allons stocker deux feuilles et arrêter la lecture

      ArrayList<String> listFruit = new ArrayList<>();



      try {

         //Obtention de notre reader

         XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(file));

         while (reader.hasNext()) {

            // Récupération de l'événement

            int type = reader.next();





            switch (type) {

                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:

                    System.out.println("Nous sommes sur un élement " + reader.getLocalName());

                    // Si c'est un début de balise, on vérifie qu'il s'agit d'une balise feuille

                    if(reader.getLocalName().equals("OptnTp")){



                       //On récupère l'évenement suivant, qui sera le contenu de la balise

                       //et on stocke dans la collection

                       reader.next();

                       listFruit.add( reader.getCharacterEncodingScheme());

                       System.out.println("\t -> Fruit récupérée ! ");

                    }



                    break;

            }



            //Si nous avons deux feuilles, on stop la lecture

            if(listFruit.size() > 2){

               System.out.println("\t --> Nombre de fruit > 1 => fin de boucle !");

               break;

            }



        }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (XMLStreamException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

      }




            System.out.println(listFruit.get(0));



   }

   }
```

here is the xml file that i'm using.

```
<CorpActnOptnDtls>
    <OptnNb>004</OptnNb>
     <OptnTp>
      <Cd>NOAC</Cd>
    </OptnTp>
    <FrctnDspstn>
      <Cd>DIST</Cd>
    </FrctnDspstn>
    <CcyOptn>EUR</CcyOptn>
    <DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
      <DfltOptnInd>true</DfltOptnInd>
    </DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
  </CorpActnOptnDtls>
```

what i'am missing?
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Please add a sample xml file to your question

Comment: any ideas? i get this output: [[C@7852e922, [C@7852e922, [C@7852e922, [C@7852e922]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run your code without any issues, I see all the tags in xml are printed out on the console.

```
     public static void main(String args[]){
     XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
         // I made only below path change to read the xml file from my windows machine
   File file = new File("C:/LocalWorkSpace/Test/src/Test1.xml");
   ArrayList<String> listFruit = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
         XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(file));
         while (reader.hasNext()) {
            int type = reader.next();
            switch (type) {
                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                    System.out.println("We are on an element " + reader.getLocalName());


                    if(reader.getLocalName().equals("OptnTp")){
                       reader.next();
                       listFruit.add( reader.getCharacterEncodingScheme());
                       System.out.println("\t -> Fruit recovered! ");
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if(listFruit.size() > 2){
               System.out.println("\t --> Number of fruit> 1 => end of loop!");
               break;
            }
        }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
            System.out.println(listFruit.get(0));

   }
```

Input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CorpActnOptnDtls>
    <OptnNb>004</OptnNb>
     <OptnTp>
      <Cd>NOAC</Cd>
    </OptnTp>
    <FrctnDspstn>
      <Cd>DIST</Cd>
    </FrctnDspstn>
    <CcyOptn>EUR</CcyOptn>
    <DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
      <DfltOptnInd>true</DfltOptnInd>
    </DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
  </CorpActnOptnDtls>
```

Console output

```
We are on an element CorpActnOptnDtls
We are on an element OptnNb
We are on an element OptnTp
     -> Fruit recovered! 
We are on an element Cd
We are on an element FrctnDspstn
We are on an element Cd
We are on an element CcyOptn
We are on an element DfltPrcgOrStgInstr
We are on an element DfltOptnInd
UTF-8
```

Comment: my problem is when i try to display the array wich must contain NOAC, try to display it please

Comment: Well I don't see in your code anywhere adding NOAC to array. If your code  updated trying to do something different & not working, update your post.